# How to inline CSS style file to HTML file with sed?

Tags: html, css, bash, sed

I'm trying to replace CSS file reference in HTML header with an inline style tag. I'm searching following line from the file.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">`

and I want to replace the previous line with a line

`<style>(content of style.css file here)</style>`

I have following sed command for the operation

`sed "s/<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\" type=\"text\/css\">/<style>$(cat style.css)<\/style>/" index.html`

However, sed does not like CSS file content in the command and gives an error.

`` sed: -e expression #1, char 84: unterminated `s' command ``

The command works OK without style.css file's content.
How to make this command perform what I want to do or is there an alternative solution to perform the same operation?

Comment: Works fine here with the command you've provided. Could you maybe share the contents of `style.css`?

Comment: https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/blob/master/coverage/htmlfiles/style.css
Please note that I'm unable to modify the style file in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed);

```
sed $'/<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text\\/css">/{e "<style>$(cat style.css)</style>"\n}' index.html
```

[Try it online! (repl.it)](https://repl.it/@0stone0/64752166#main.sh)

Comment: Can't really cope what is happening in this syntax, but
`sh: 1: `
bugs me in the output file.

Comment: What SED version are you using? GNU? Or are you on MacOs or so?

Comment: I have GNU sed 4.4 on Ubuntu 18.04.